# Create file with certain size

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Is there any method to create a file of desired size whenever I create a file using CreateFile().

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SetEndOfFile** can be used to extend or truncate a file.

Answer (score 0):

I think (in case you are sitting in front of a *nix box) you can handle this with the default low-lewel [write()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) / [fsync()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fsync) APIs.

Regards,
dley

Answer (score 0):

you might use, at the prompt (with admin credentials), "fsutil file createnew" followed by the file name and the desired size (in bytes)